# Delete button working in ajax but problems with PHP method

Tags: php, button

I'm trying to make a button that deletes a certain item with a certain FeatureID in my database.
I have to do this using ajax, which worked but I also need a backup for people who don't have javascript enabled.

```
if ($_SESSION['UserID'] == "1") 
                {
                    echo '<form method="post" id ="featureDelete" name="featureDelete" action="ajax-follow.php?type=delete&amp;id=' . $row['FeatureID'] . '"><button data-id=' . $row['FeatureID'] .' class="delete" > Delete </button></form>' . '<br>';

                }
```

that was the code I used for my button and it gets me to this link

```
http://localhost:8080/phptesting/ajax-follow.php?type=delete&id=27
```

with the error:

> Notice: Undefined index: featureDelete in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\phptesting\ajax-follow.php on line 23

` 
and this is the code I'm using on my **ajax-follow.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
include_once('class/db.class.php');
include_once('class/features.class.php');
include_once 'class/vote.class.php';


$v = new vote();
$f = new feature();

if (!empty($_POST['featureID'])) 
{
    if (($_POST['type']) == "vote") 
    {
        $v->setM_iFeatureID($_POST['featureID']);
        $v->setM_iUserID($_SESSION['UserID']);

        $v->save();      
    }

}
      if (($_POST['type']) == "delete") 
      {
        $f->Delete($_POST['featureID']);
        header('Location: features.php');
       }
```

I have a few questions:

- Is this a good way to do this (This is my first time doing a delete
  button)
- How can I fix my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never include the `?` and parameters in a form's `action` attribute, ever.  They will get truncated from the request.  Put the parameters that are to be hardcoded (so far as the webbrowser knows) in `<input type='hidden' name='param' value='whatever' />`

Instead of

```
<form method="post" id="featureDelete" name="featureDelete" 
action="ajax-follow.php?type=delete&amp;id={$row['FeatureID']}">
```

Do

```
<form method="post" id="featureDelete" name="featureDelete" 
action="ajax-follow.php">
   <input type='hidden' name='type' value='delete' />
   <input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?php echo $row['FeatureID']; ?>' />
....
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You are adding a query string to the `action` attribute of the form. These variables will be available in `$_GET` and not in `$_POST`. Apart from that, when you manipulate a database you should always use POST instead of GET.

An easy way to get your form work the regular / no-ajax way, is to add hidden fields to your form:

```
<form method="post" ...>
  <input type="hidden" name="the_name_you_need" value="the_value_required">
  ...
</form>
```

Now the variables will be available in `$_POST` like you expect them to be.